# chisq.test with numeric variables

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have the following table:

| Word | Cat | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shiwu | DE | 214 |
| shiwu | N | 190 |
| dongxi | DE | 1308 |
| dongxi | N | 925 |

How do I run chisq.test to test if the DE/N ratio of shiwu (214/190) is significantly different from the DE/N ratio of dongxi (1308/925)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code could be useful.

```
tibble(Word = c("shiwu", "shiwu", "dongxi", "dongxi"),
       Cat = c("DE", "N", "DE", "N"),
       Num = c(214, 190, 1308, 925)) %>% # build tibble (like data frame)
  pivot_wider(names_from = Cat, values_from = Num) %>% # structuring it as a table
  column_to_rownames("Word") %>% # defining first column (Word) as rownames
  as.matrix() %>% # converting data for a contigency table
  chisq.test() # executing chi-squared test
```

The answer will be a result of Pearson Chi-squared test with Yates correction (this correction, for this data will not influence the result).

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  .
X-squared = 4.1782, df = 1, p-value = 0.04095
```

Good job